# What was that symbol Starbuck painted?

Tags: battlestar-galactica

Starbuck painted a symbol of concentric circles. What was the significance?

[image: The symbol]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is the eye of the maelstrom, or storm.

It's both literal and symbolic.  It's literal in that it represents the storm she flies into in the episode [*Maelstrom*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maelstrom_%28Battlestar_Galactica%29):

> In this episode, she flies down into a gas giant while in pursuit of a Cylon Raider.  When she flies down into a storm, the storm has an appearance like the painting she made earlier.  The first time she is scared and pulls up.  The second time, on another mission, she flies down in, after the Raider, and doesn't eject when she needs to and is lost and presumed dead.

The symbolic meaning of the image is the emotional maelstrom that is the fear she needs to face, including fear of death.  It's the storm she has to go through to find peace, which she finds in the symbolic center of the storm:

> When she finds the courage to dive down the 2nd time and chase the Cylon, she is going into both a real and a symbolic storm, having won the struggle with her fear (which is represented by the maelstrom) and she finds peace in the eye of the storm where she dies.

Answer (score 9):

As well as being the eye of the storm in the gas giant in [Maelstrom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maelstrom_%28Battlestar_Galactica%29), it is also the symbol ([the Eye of Jupiter](http://servewithchips.blogspot.com/2008/04/galactica-endeavor-eye-of-jupiter-3x11.html)) found in the Temple of Five in the episode [The Eye of Jupiter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Eye_of_Jupiter_%28Battlestar_Galactica%29) - although, this is only realised by Helo at the end of the next episode.

> The symbol in the temple apparently represents a supernova which takes place shortly after the human and cylon confrontation over the temple. This supernova leads the humans to discover another supernova which acts as a marker pointing toward Earth